# Como Tirar o "redimensionamento" de um textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

```js
< script src = "//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js" > < /script> <
  script > tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea'
  }); < /script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ">
    <textarea id="txtDesc" name="message" rows="5" maxlength="1000" runat="server" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade acredito que o seu problema é por causa do **TinyMCE**

Veja o que diz a documentação sobre o `resize` https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#resize

Script do componente para remover o  `resize`

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  resize: false
});
```

Comment: Obrigado mano, era exatamente esse o problema

Comment: @DaniloGonçalves que bom que resolveu, tmj!

Answer (score 0):

A seguinte propriedade do css, desabilita o comportamento de resize do textarea

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: Já fiz dessa forma e não funciona de jeito nenhum

Comment: Você já tentou adicionar uma largura e altura fixa pra ele? Por exemplo: textarea { resize: none; height: 300px;  width: 100%;  }

Answer (score 0):

Fala Dan, apenas adicione `resize: none;` para a tag. Se quiser, ainda pode manipular sua altura e largura via css.

Exemplo:

```css
textarea#example {
  resize: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="example"> Exemplo para ex aluno da UNASP </textarea>
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda Jorge, o problema estava no plugin do meu textarea, na tag script eu deveria manipular o resize, o cara ai de cima me passou o que deveria ser feito, Obrigado novamente